# how to fix Error c2373 InterlockedCompareExchange redefinition: different type modifier

Tags: c++, qt

I have just added the QT dll to a new C++ project in Visual Studio 2010, no code added. But when I build the project I have error message:

```
Error   62  error C2373: '_InterlockedCompareExchange' : redefinition; different type modifiers C:\Users\bap\Desktop\cPlus\LIBRARY\QtCore\qatomic_msvc.h    128 // Code Clarity
```

Please tell me how to fix that.

Comment: Are you sure your Qt's version corresponds to the one of VS? May be there are other error messages present? Could you also please provide the details about how you "have just added the QT dll"?

Comment: thanks for reply. I install other version of QT and done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by trying different different calling conversions in your project.(e.g. from stdcall to cdecl)